# Data files from EXCEL for MySQL

Tags: mysql, excel

I was trying to output Excel's data to a text file to use them in MySQL, nevertheless i was not able to find an easy solutio because at the end of each row I have to add manually a "TAB" ! Otherwise there are always errors in the MySQL table, is there any special data format to export these data from Excel 2003 ?

Thanx for your help

Alex

Comment: This appears to be very similiar to [8031193](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031193)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load from CSV (comma separated value) format.  [See here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html).  Are you saving your Excel data as tab separated?  If so, save as comma separated and follow instructions in the link.

EDIT:

You probably need to include the

```
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

statement.  See [this blog](http://blog.tjitjing.com/index.php/2008/02/import-excel-data-into-mysql-in-5-easy.html).

Comment: I tried also with commas but I need to add a comma at the end of the row. Manually and that's the same issue as with TABs

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?  The MySQL documentation examples do not show a comma at the end.