# Extract Transform Load into MySql

Tags: mysql, csv, etl, talend

Am basically from Microsoft background working much on SSIS for ETL sought of project.

Now I got another project on hand to deal with loading of .csv files into MySql database.  In process of loading these tables data has to go through some transformations and then into destination table.  It is much of ETL project.

**Client doesn't have SSIS (BIDS) and am compelled to use open source tools.**

I did bit of research and found **Talend Data Integration** tool best fits for my situation.

As am new to this environment and am sure there are experts in this area, I need some advice on best tools to do ETL of this type and best practices.

If need any futher information please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, PhpMyAdmin can import CSV into MySQL, and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8143110/loading-csv-files-into-mysql-workbench) is about a similar topic too, but these don't come close to what SSIS can offer...

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right Talend Open Studio is pretty good tool with hundreds of connector, 
in your case just create job which take CSV as your source and MySQl is destination apply any transformation if required and load it.

you can get more information on CSV to MySQL load with examples [Talend forum](http://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewforum.php?id=2)

if you have any base plan then, share with me, I can guide you how to transfer CSV to MySQL table.