# Import Excel file into MySql (not a CSV)

Tags: mysql, excel

I'm having issues importing a CSV file into my MySQL database because of all the quotes an commas. If I remove them from the CSV, the import works fine. However, my data is ruined. So I'm looking for a way to import an Excel spreadsheet file into a MySQL database.

Is there a way to import an Excel spreadsheet (or another format I can save to) directly into a blank MySQL database table?

Comment: This appears to be very similiar to [8031193](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031193)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC Excel files (*.xls etc) cannot be imported in MySQL as they are a binary formatted file. However you could try using a TSV (tab delimited) thereby removing your comma issue. Cant rememer the exact syntax but something like:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/data.csv' into Table Fields terminated by '\t' lines terminated by '\n'
```

Alternatively you'll need to build a helper app for this.

Answer (score 0):

@Simon is right - You can't import XLS directly into MySQL.

When I run into this problem, I use the `SED` via Terminal.  to remove the quotes.  I'm sure there is a more elegant way to do it, but it works for me and it doesn't take much time.

```
sed  ‘s/"//g’ filename.csv > newfilename.csv
```

Then, import that newfilename.csv.

Alternatively, you can open the CSV in a text editor and find/replace the quotes.