# Round Trip INTO OUTFILE, Excel Editing, and LOAD DATA INFILE without corruption

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile, into-outfile

I have been trying to export a mysql table with INTO OUTFILE to CSV for editing in Excel and then inserting back into mysql using LOAD DATA INFILE.

I can export ok, and even reinsert the unedited file. However, if I open in Excel make changes and then save things get screwed up. I select "Yes" when it asks if I'm sure I want to export in CSV, but even if I try and reopen the file in Excel it comes up with invalid format.

I am wondering what the proper settings "FIELDS ESCAPED BY, TERMINATED, etc." would be for each command to ensure compatibility with Excel.

Thanks,

Comment: If it helps, I have all types of data, dollar amounts, decimal values with percentage, etc. The table to reinsert is comprised of varchar fields.

Comment: This appears to be very similiar to [8031193](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031193)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
SELECT < > FROM <blah>
INTO OUTFILE '<filename>' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

You can also do:

```
SELECT < > FROM <blah>
INTO OUTFILE '<filename>'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

You can also use '|' as delimiter and import the file as delimited.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That cuts off anywhere I have a comma and replaces the remainder of the field with '\'. I can add ENCLOSED BY '"'  ... that gets the data to excel fine, but when I edit and save it messes up on the LOAD DATA INFILE.

Comment: @christian Do you have tabs in the columns?

Comment: Excel doesn't seem to support the tab option. I'm trying to allow users to easily edit their data so trying to avoid extra steps.

Comment: @christian Excel allows import of a text file that is delimited by something else you can also try just making it an .xls file and try to open it.

Comment: I'm sure there is a way to import with another delimiter, but I'm just trying to make things as simple as possible for the user. I am able to export to csv ok, so I think I am going to try and use fgetcsv instead to import the data. I am processing after the fact, so the insertion speed is not as big a factor as the export speed.

Comment: No, from MYSQL database. I can export many records in seconds with INTO OUTFILE.

Comment: @christian The delimiter won't change the speed of export.